# Can We get add contact intent with contact picker?

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts, contactpicker

I want to use the contact picker intent to pick the contacts. Also I want the function of adding contacts in my activity. There is an intent to add contacts, nut I want to know that can we use this both together as used in the contacts app in android?

Like this:

[image]

Can We use contact picker as well as add contact intent? Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

No.

`ACTION_PICK` will allow you to pick a contact. However, there is no way for you to request that the contact-picker UI offer an add-contact option. Furthermore, there is no requirement for a contact-picker UI to even *have* an add-contact option.

If you want to allow the user to add a contact, have your own UI trigger an `ACTION_INSERT` or `ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT` activity:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.inserter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents.Insert;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ContactsInserter extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.insert);

    btn.setOnClickListener(onInsert);
  }

  View.OnClickListener onInsert=new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      EditText fld=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
      String name=fld.getText().toString();

      fld=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);

      String phone=fld.getText().toString();
      Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);

      i.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
      i.putExtra(Insert.NAME, name);
      i.putExtra(Insert.PHONE, phone);
      startActivity(i);
    }
  };
}
```

(from [this old sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Contacts/Inserter))